Typescript fails to warn against an invalid method override (because it fails to detect contravariant relationship)
I think TS fails to warn against an invalid method override.
In the following code, Dog extends Animal. But Dog is a consumer of DogFood, a subclass of Food, and Animal is a consumer of Food. So the relationship between Animal/Dog is contravariant to the relationship of Food/DogFood. Therefore, Dog shouldn't be allowed to extend Animal here because the consumer Dog.eat(food:DogFood) can't override (is not assignable to) Animal.eat(food:Food).
And yet TS fails to emit any errors.
TS should have emitted an error like:

Property 'eat' in type 'Dog' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Animal'.
Type (food:DogFood)=>void is not assignable to type (food:Food)=>void

But it doesn't emit errors.
This problem is made evident when I run the code and it outputs [LOG]: "eating dry dog food owned by undefined".
    class Animal {
      eat(food:Food){console.log(`eating regular food. Weight: ${food.weight}`)}
    }
    class Dog extends Animal { //this extends shouldn't be allowed. Type (food:DogFood)=>void shouldn't be assignable to type (food:Food)=>void
      eat(food:DogFood){console.log(`eating ${food.isWet?"wet":"dry"} dog food owned by ${food.owner}`)}
    }
    class Food {
      weight: number=1;
    }
    class DogFood extends Food {
      isWet:boolean=true;
      owner:Dog;
      constructor(owner: Dog) {
        super()
        this.owner=owner
      }
    }
    const pet:Animal=new Dog()
    const food:Food=new Food()
    pet.eat(food) //"eating dry dog food owned by undefined" 

Likewise doing this through generic Interfaces also doesn't make TS catch the mistakes. In the TS handbook it is said: "TypeScript automatically infers the variance of every generic type". I guess it doesn't though.
interface ConsumerOf<F> {
  eat(food:F):void
}
class InterfacedAnimal implements ConsumerOf<Food> {
  eat(food:Food){console.log(`eating regular food. Weight: ${food.weight}`)}
}
class InterfacedDog extends InterfacedAnimal implements ConsumerOf<DogFood>  { //this extends shouldn't be allowed. Type (food:DogFood)=>void shouldn't be assignable to type (food:Food)=>void
  eat(food:DogFood){console.log(`eating ${food.isWet?"wet":"dry"} dog food owned by ${food.owner}`)}
}
const pet2:InterfacedAnimal=new InterfacedDog()
const food2:Food=new Food()
pet2.eat(food2) //"eating dry dog food owned by undefined" 

// again, TS points no errors here
const derivedConsumer:ConsumerOf<DogFood>=new InterfacedDog()
const baseConsumer:ConsumerOf<Food>=derivedConsumer  //this shouldn't be allowed. Type (food:DogFood)=>void shouldn't be assignable to type (food:Food)=>void

The idea here is that a function that takes a derived type as input shouldn't be assignable to a function that takes a base type as input
interface Base{}
interface Derived extends Base{}
declare function d(x:Derived):void
const b:(x:Base)=>void = d //shouldn't be allowed because type "(x:Derived)=>void" shouldn't be assignable to type "(x:Base)=>void"

Shouldn't TS catch these contravariant relationships and complain?

Methods are bivariant on purpose in TS, yes it's not safe. You can change to function-valued properties if you really care about this, like this approach shows. I'll find an appropriate duplicate
